# VIM: turn off autocomplete but keep hint

Tags: vim

I am new to VIM, and I come from Eclipse/VS world.

It seems that when I use **Ctrl + N**, it auto completes the function, and when I type *sys* (I intend to get *syslog*), it automatically auto completes the name to *sysSync* (the first item in the hint list is sysSync).

The problem is that the sys is auto completed to sysSync. When i continue to type l, it becomes sysSyncl, instead of sysl. I found it is too annoying.

My question is how can I turn off the auto complete but get the hint window open, like when I type *sys*, it leaves the *sys* untouched, but gives me the hint list to choose from?

What should I put in my `.vimrc` file?

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE. It describes a setup where the first entry of the popup menu is only selected (so you can accept it quickly via CTRL-Y), but not yet inserted into the text (so you can continue typing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do *exactly* what you want, but keep in mind that you can keep *CTRL* pressed, and loop through the suggestions with *N*.

Comment: And if you want to dismiss the list and not have it autocomplete anything, hit `Ctrl+E`.

Comment: that's not really the problem. say i know i have a function called sys**log. i forget what is in the middle. in Eclipse/VS , i can type sys, then ctrl+space, i got the hint list. and if i continue type. it will narrow down the list to the funtion name i want. go though the list by ctl/arrow keys is not feasible in this case, since the list will be very long.